# Distribution in Heston

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, probability

$$dV_t=-k(V_t-1)dt+ \epsilon\sqrt{V_t}dW_t$$
$W_t$ is wiener process and the rest is just some parameters.

For $T_{i+1}>T_{i}$ how do I find the expectation and variance of $V_{T_{i+1}}$ ***conitional*** to $V_{T_i}$?

Comment: The same as how you do it for $T>0$ knowing $V_0$: it is a CIR process see e.g. here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox–Ingersoll–Ross_model

Comment: The derivation/proof is not given in wiki..

Comment: Did you try googling now that you know what kind of process it is? There should be plenty of information available, even on this stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @Quantuple, we may consider a more general Cox-Ingersoll-Ross model
$$
{\rm d}r_t=a\left(b-r_t\right){\rm d}t+\sigma\sqrt{r_t}{\rm d}w_t.
$$
Integrating this equation on $t\in\left(u,v\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^+$ yields
\begin{align}
r_v-r_u=\int_u^v{\rm d}r_t&=\int_u^v\left[a\left(b-r_t\right){\rm d}t+\sigma\sqrt{r_t}{\rm d}w_t\right]\\
&=ab\left(v-u\right)-a\int_u^vr_t{\rm d}t+\sigma\int_u^v\sqrt{r_t}{\rm d}w_t.
\end{align}
Acting $\mathbb{E}\left(\cdot|r_u\right)$ on both sides of this equality gives
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(r_v|r_u\right)-r_u&=\mathbb{E}\left(r_v-r_u|r_u\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[ab\left(v-u\right)-a\int_u^vr_t{\rm d}t+\sigma\int_u^v\sqrt{r_t}{\rm d}w_t\Bigg|r_u\right]\\
&=ab\left(v-u\right)-a\mathbb{E}\left(\int_u^vr_t{\rm d}t\Bigg|r_u\right)+\sigma\mathbb{E}\left(\int_u^v\sqrt{r_t}{\rm d}w_t\Bigg|r_u\right)\\
&=ab\left(v-u\right)-a\mathbb{E}\left(\int_u^vr_t{\rm d}t\Bigg|r_u\right)\\
&=ab\left(v-u\right)-a\int_u^v\mathbb{E}\left(r_t|r_u\right){\rm d}t.
\end{align}
Denote $f(t)=\mathbb{E}\left(r_t|r_u\right)$ for $t\ge u$, and the last equation is equivalent to, for all $v\ge u$,
$$
f(v)=r_u+ab\left(v-u\right)-a\int_u^vf(t){\rm d}t.
$$
Regard this as an integral equation with respect to $v$, and its respective differential equation with initial condition reads
\begin{align}
f'(v)&=ab-af(v),\\
f(u)&=r_u.
\end{align}
This system immediately leads to

> $$
> \mathbb{E}\left(r_v|r_u\right)=f(v)=r_ue^{-a\left(v-u\right)}+b\left(1-e^{-a\left(v-u\right)}\right).
> $$

Based on the result above, we may figure out $\mathbb{E}\left(r_v^2|r_u\right)$ as follows. Thanks to Ito's formula, the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross model gives
\begin{align}
{\rm d}\left(r_t^2\right)=2r_t{\rm d}r_t+{\rm d}\left<r\right>_t&=2ar_t\left(b-r_t\right){\rm d}t+\sigma r_t\sqrt{r_t}{\rm d}w_t+\sigma^2r_t{\rm d}t\\
&=\left[\left(2ab+\sigma^2\right)r_t-2ar_t^2\right]{\rm d}t+\sigma r_t\sqrt{r_t}{\rm d}w_t.
\end{align}
Again, Integrating this equation on $t\in\left(u,v\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^+$ yields
$$
r_v^2-r_u^2=\left(2ab+\sigma^2\right)\int_u^vr_t{\rm d}t-2a\int_u^vr_t^2{\rm d}t+\sigma\int_u^vr_t\sqrt{r_t}{\rm d}w_t.
$$
Acting $\mathbb{E}\left(\cdot|r_u\right)$ on this equality yields
$$
g(v)-r_u^2=\left(2ab+\sigma^2\right)\int_u^vf(t){\rm d}t-2a\int_u^vg(t){\rm d}t,
$$
where $f$ agrees with the notation from above, while $g(v)=\mathbb{E}\left(r_t^2|r_u\right)$. Note that its respective differential equation reads
\begin{align}
g'(v)&=\left(2ab+\sigma^2\right)f(v)-2ag(v),\\
g(u)&=r_u^2.
\end{align}
Thanks to this system, we could eventually figure out

> \begin{align}
> \text{Var}\left(r_v^2|r_u\right)&=\mathbb{E}\left(r_v^2|r_u\right)-\mathbb{E}^2\left(r_v|r_u\right)=g(v)-f^2(v)\\
> &=\frac{\sigma^2}{a}\left[r_ue^{-a\left(v-u\right)}\left(1-e^{-a\left(v-u\right)}\right)+\frac{b}{2}\left(1-e^{-a\left(v-u\right)}\right)^2\right].
> \end{align}

The answer to your original question could be obtained by taking $a=k$, $b=1$, $\sigma=\epsilon$, $u=T_i$ and $v=T_{I+1}$.